# The digest-uri does not match any LDAP SPN's registered for this server

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap, openldap, sasl

My goal is to authenticate an "Active Directory's User" using SASL with  the DIGEST-MD5 mechanism from a Ubuntu's terminal.

I typed the following command:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://test.my.company:389 -b "DC=test,DC=my,DC=company" -D "CN=Aron Herrera,CN=Users,DC=test,DC=my,DC=company" -U aron -w "my-password" -Y DIGEST-MD5
```

And I got:

```
SASL/DIGEST-MD5 authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Invalid credentials (49)
    additional info: 80090303: LdapErr: DSID-0C0904B2, comment: The digest-uri does not match any LDAP SPN's registered for this server., data 0, v1db0
```

Could you give me any information (links, tutorials, docs) to get my goal ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently stumbled into the same problem. After torturing my brain for some hours I went and captured some packets using **Wireshark**. The problem you, and I, are having is related to the way *ldapsearch* handles the *digest-uri*.

First it does a DNS lookup on **test.my.company** (obviously) and uses the **IP** obtained to build the *digest-uri*. It ends like this: *ldap/10.10.10.10* (for example). This is **not** what your AD server expects.

If you use **ldp.exe** to examine the machine holding the Active Directory role you will see an LDAP attribute called **serviceProviderName**. It does look like *ldap/test.my.company* (plus other variations), but none of these have the **IP** in it.

Some have suggested adding a PTR to your DNS server to the **test.my.company** server. It did not work for me. Other tried adding a new SPN (**serviceProviderName**) to the AD machine LDAP attribute (I would not do this if my life depended on it).

I think this has something to do with how *ldapsearch* is implemented. The same test performed with Apache's Directory Studio went fine.

Answer (score 0):

The error `DSID-0C090569: The digest-uri does not match any LDAP SPN's registered for this server.` can be avoided by using `SASL_NOCANON on` or the `-N` option:

From `man ldap.conf`:

> SASL_NOCANON: Do not perform reverse DNS lookups to canonicalize SASL host names. The default is off.

From `man ldapsearch`:

> -N     Do not use reverse DNS to canonicalize SASL host name.

I have the following in my `~/.ldaprc`:

```
uri ldaps://ldap.mycompany.com
base DC=corp,DC=mycompany,DC=com
sasl_mech DIGEST-MD5
SASL_NOCANON on
SASL_AUTHCID rubelagu
SASL_REALM
VERSION 3
```

And I can search the Active Directory LDAP with `ldapsearch  '(displayName=Marei*)'.